# Change password for all users accounts in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command

Alright, I need something of a batch scripting guru to help me out of the corner that I've backed myself into.

I have a program that runs as system and I want to change the password for all the accounts that appear in the output for net user.  I'm not really sure how I could do this with just command line or AHK-based scripting.

When I perform a net user command the output is like this for me:

```
C:\Users\Resident>net user

User accounts for \\9100BASELINE

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            Guest                    Resident
The command completed successfully.
```

I need some way to change the password on all the accounts here (be it 3 or 50) to something of my choosing.

Can anyone help me out with this?  I tried slapping together a for loop where each item is a token before I realized that I don't know how to regex the usernames out of there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend employing the help of a little VBScript:

```
Set accounts = GetObject("WinNT://.")
accounts.Filter = Array("user")
For Each user In accounts
  WScript.Echo user.Name
Next
```

Save it as `listusers.vbs` and run it like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set /p "newpw=Enter new password: "

for /f "delims=" %%u in ('cscript //NoLogo C:\path\to\listusers.vbs') do (
  net user "%%u" "%newpw%"
)
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to omit specific accounts from being processed you can either add an exclude list to the VBScript:

```
Set exclude = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
exclude.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
exclude.Add "HomeGroupUser$", True
exclude.Add "otheruser", True
...

Set accounts = GetObject("WinNT://.")
accounts.Filter = Array("user")
For Each user In accounts
  If Not exclude.Exists(user.Name) Then WScript.Echo user.Name
Next
```

or filter the output of `listusers.vbs` with `findstr`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%u in (
  'cscript //NoLogo C:\path\to\listusers.vbs ^| findstr /v /i ^
    /c:HomeGroupUser$ /c:otheruser ...'
) do (
  net user "%%u" "%newpw%"
)
```

Comment: My only concern with this is that it grabs $homegroup as well as all the other users... I don't really care because I don't have any networked devices. But that might be a pain for some people.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this purely with batch.

The simplest method would be to list all the folders with:

```
cd C:\Users
dir /b /o:n /ad > users.txt
```

After that, you'd use a for loop that sets a password to each user in the Users directory, and makes sure that the script doesn't try to set a password for the Public folder, as it is not a user.

It'd look like this:

```
for /f %%i in ('type C:\Users\users.txt') do(
if not %%i==Public (
net user %%i [Insert Password Here]
)
)
```

Technically, you don't actually have to check for extra non user folders, as cmd won't actually cause any problems if it attempts to set a password for a non user folder.